# Right way to create Libraries in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Could any one tell me the right way to create libraries from below options.

```
     //option 1

     function Fruit(){
       var color,shape;
       this.start = function(l,callback){
         color = "Red"; shape = "Circle";
         return callback();
       }           
     }

    //option2

    function Fruit(){

       this.start = function(l,callback){
         this.color = "Red"; this.shape = "Circle";
         return callback();
       }           
     }

     //option3

    var Fruit = {
        var color,shape;
        start : function (l,callback) {
             color = "Red"; shape = "Circle";
             return callback(); 
        }
     }
```

I want to know which is the right way to create Objects and Functions inside of it. If all three options are wrong, could any one tell me the right way.

Comment: Your option 3 is a syntax error, so it's not an option. Also it seems to create an object, not a constructor function.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572) for the difference between your first two options. However, there are many ways to write libraries with class constructors, all of them different, and none of them wrong - there is no "right way".

Comment: I flagged the question because they are as many "good" ways to create objects than expert javascript developers and libraries

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference, however, there are many ways of skinning a cat. Feel free to change the names of vars etc...

```
//option 4

 function Fruit(_fruit, _callback){
   var that = this;
   this.color = '';
   this.shape = '';

   var init = function(f, c){
     switch(f){
       case 'apple':
         that.color = 'red';
         that.shape = 'circle'
       break;
     }
     return c();
   }

   init(_fruit, _callback);           
 }

 var apple = new Fruit('apple', function(){
   // Although you don't really need a callback as you're not doing any async tasks...
   alert('Apple generated');
 });
```